# Which is more grammatically correct;

Tags: grammaticality

Which is more grammatically correct - a guide to things to do or a guide of things to do?

Comment: How about "a guide on things to do".

Comment: As with most such questions, neither is more grammatical and each means something different. It may be more felicitous to ask about the nuances that each has.

Comment: There is "no such thing" as "grammatically correct" English. Even pidgin English would be "grammatically correct", if it conforms to a regional set of grammatical patterns. Such questions should be , "is it grammatically acceptable" within the circles of formal English usage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A guide *to* things to do would be, for example, a guide book. A guide *of* things to do would give the impression that the things to do are themselves being guided. In the second case "guide" takes on the feeling of "guidelines".